# VHDL - How to implement AdHoc network

Tags: vhdl, fpga, adhoc

how can I implement an AdHoc network in fpga using the vhdl programming language. I am using a Scientech st101 with wireless communication kit.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean an 802.11 Ad Hoc network?  If so, that's a large system you'll need to build, including some software, some logic and some analogue hardware.  [What makes you think VHDL is the right tool for the whole job](http://parallelpoints.com/why-use-an-fpga/)?